# My custom model's loss converged to a high value(Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, loss, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm training my custom model that detects only person.
I used tensorflow object detection API and followed [this github document](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10).
I got images from coco dataset.
400 test images and 1600 train images are prepared.
Here is my train config.

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 6
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0001
          decay_steps: 250
          decay_factor: 0.9
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
```

And environment.

```
Tensorflow : 1.13.1 gpu
GPU : GTX 1070
CDUA : 10.0
cuDNN : 7.4.2
```

According to above github document, the loss should be under 2.
But my model's loss always converges to 4.
Is there any problems??
I can't figure out what is wrong...
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Try increasing the data set or add noise in some images so that it can generalize well. Also, try changing the optimizer to adam.

Comment: @AniketBote I've incresed the data set 3 times and changed the optimizer to adam. I hope that this will work! Could you tell me how many images are recommended at least? I used ssd mobilenet v2 quantized 300x300 coco as pre-trained model, I forgot to write it down in this post.